# How to provide an instance in Angular2 NOT from main bootstrap?

Tags: angular

I know the question may seem trivial but it's not. let me explain.
For a component to provide an instacne to all its children, well that's easy enough, you just do:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'Starwars',
   directives: [ShoppingComponent],
   template: `<shopping></shopping>`,
   providers: [CartActions]
})
```

However, I am trying to share an instance with my Component's children that I have manually instantiated through new.. as in:

```
export class Starwars {
    private appStore:any;
    constructor() {
        this.appStore = new AppStore();

        // tried this with no luck
        var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
            provide(AppStore, {useValue: this.appStore})
        ]);

        // tried this with no luck
        provide(AppStore, {useFactory: () => {
            return this.appStore;
        }})
    }
}
```

and also tried these with no luck:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'Starwars',
    directives: [ShoppingComponent],
    template: `<shopping></shopping>`,
    providers: [CartActions, PartActions,
        provide(AppStore, {useValue: this.appStore})
    ]
})
```

as well as useClass... so as I was saying, I am trying to share a manually instantiated class with my component's children, and NOT a component that I dependency injected and had Angular2 instantiate for me...

Comment: I'm a bit confused with exactly what you need, but if you are instantiating the objects yourself I don't think you need an injector, why dont you just pass the object you created as an `@Input` to the children? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html

Comment: I don't think its possible, have a look at my answer why. I propose posting the question in another form explaining the use case, like for example: "How to do X the Angular 2 way?", X being the use case

Comment: I am using a Mediator but rather DI if I could... which doesn't seem like its possible... tx

Comment: Didnt really play with this, but did you try also useFactory? Maybe you can create the instance with parameters and return it?

Comment: yes I did try the factory, but the results were the same and I was not able to pass params to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This is AFIK not possible in Angular 2.

For example, there are ways to dynamically inject a component at runtime via `DynamicComponentLoader`. but we cannot override the providers of that component, they are inside the component metadata with is protected via a closure at runtime and cannot be edited. There are no lifecycle hooks that relate to dependency injection either.

There is simply no mechanism in place to allow what you are trying to do, 
and there are mechanisms in place actually to avoid it, like making providers read-only. There is no provider type that allows to be called at runtime from the components either.

It looks that what you are attempting is not possible by design. This is probably a good thing because it avoids the dependency injection mechanism from being used in unexpected ways.

Comment: ok tx for the feedback, but I am not really trying to override the DI, but rather just create an instance manually on the parent component and provide it to the children, and by the way, the reason is that this component requires constructor arguments, which you can't pass when doing dependency injections (AFIK)